# How can I simplify this method in Java?

Tags: java

How can I simplify this expression in Java

```
public Map<String, List<Account>> findAllAccountsCredits(final List<String> listOfIds) {
    List<Account> accountCredit = executeQueryForAccountCredits(listOfIds);
    Map<String, List<Account>> groupedByOwnerId = accountCredit.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getOwnerId));
    Map<String, List<Account>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Account>> entry : groupedByOwnerId.entrySet()) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), getSortedValues(entry.getValue()));
    }

    return result;
}
```

My point is, then for each key, I want to sort its values ​​according to `getSortedValues​​(entry.getValue ())`. But here, instead of doing it in one line, I'm functionally making another new object and loop.

```
Map<String, List<Account>> result = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Account>> entry : groupedByOwnerId.entrySet()) {
    result.put(entry.getKey(), getSortedValues(entry.getValue()));
}
```

How can I simplify this method while keeping the operation as it is now.

Comment: What does `getSortedValues` do?

Comment: sorts values in custom way, and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `accountCredit.sort(...);` before `stream`:

```
public Map<String, List<Account>> findAllAccountsCredits(final List<String> listOfIds) {
    List<Account> accountCredit = executeQueryForAccountCredits(listOfIds);
    accountCredit.sort(...);
    return accountCredit.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getOwnerId));
}
```

Comment: or use `.sorted(...)` in stream pipeline

Comment: @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks Sure, this could be as an option as well